# Division of values in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, division

In this data frame

```
      SuperHero  Male  Female  TOTAL
0           Thor    26      12     38
1          Marvel    12      32     44
2          Other    10       8     18
3          TOTAL    48      52    10
```

0

how to perform division on two values.

**For example:**

```
a=df.iloc[[0], [3]]
b=df.iloc[[3], [3]]

p=a/b
print(a)
print(b)
print(float(p))
```

**The Output for the above code**

TOTAL
0     38
TOTAL
3    100

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-cfe71c8d8503> in <module>
      4 print(a)
      5 print(b)
----> 6 print(float(p))
      7 

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'DataFrame'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are actually getting a dataframe in return from the .iloc function
You just need a slight modification in your code:

```
a=df.iloc[0,3]
b=df.iloc[3,3]

p=a/b
print(a)
print(b)
print(float(p))
```

output

```
38
100
0.38
```

Comment: I have made changes to the answer, since this is much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing the values in your dataframe like this:

```
a = df.iloc[0,3]
b = df.iloc[3,3]
```